# How to change image according to language choice (i18n gem in Rails)?

Tags: html, css, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am willing to change a picture based on the choice of the language. It is because my image contains some text and I made three different versions of the image according to language choice (Dutch, French and English). How do I need to do that?

I tried to add my 
`<%= image_tag("lansink_en.png", class: "center-image") %>` in my different `en.yml`, `fr.yml`and `nl.yml` files but it didn't work out.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the html content in your yaml files. So say you have a yml like

```
en:
  url: '<%= image_tag("lansink_en.png", class: "center-image") %>'
```

Then to display it you do:

```
<%= raw t('url') %>
```

Then just set your other locale files and you're all set

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion that translation files should not contain code or any more specific markup than is strictly semantic.

If they get shipped to translators (or auto-translated with something like Google Translate), then English *code* could get translated, leaving you with something broken in one or more languages, and something working in the others.

If you change your class-names, it shouldn't require a round of translation or a bypass for this special case.

I'd prefer a good-old helper method:

```
module SomeHelper
  def lansink_image_tag
    image_tag("lansink_#{I18n.locale}.png", class: "center-image")
  end        
end
```

Or, if you don't know that all languages will necessarily have a file, but you want a fallback:

```
module SomeHelper
  def lansink_image_tag
    has_image = [:de, :fr, :en]
    suffix = has_image.include?(I18n.locale) ? I18n.locale : :en
    image_tag("lansink_#{suffix}.png", class: "center-image")
  end        
end
```